# Optimization problem involving an entrywise function

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

Let $X$ a $n\times p$ real-valued matrix and $Y$ a $p\times q$ real-valued matrix. Let $\phi:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function. What is the appropriate way to deal with the following optimization problem: Find the infimum over all semi-definite positive matrices $\Sigma$ of size $n\times n$ of the quantity:
$$H = ||\phi(X^T \Sigma X)^{-1} Y||^2$$
where $\phi(.)$ is taken entrywise , $^T$ denotes the transpose operator, and $^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of the matrix.

Comment: note that $X^\top\Sigma X$ need not be invertible.

Comment: and of course if you do not  say anything about $\phi$ then it looks pretty hopeless,

Comment: Ok, if you want, assume that $\phi(x)=\tanh(x)$ if it helps.